# Non local median filter - Undefined function for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to clean some images using the non local mean filter functions from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27395-fast-non-local-means-1d--2d-color-and-3d). When I run the code, I get the error `Undefined function 'image2vectors_double' for input arguments of type 'double'`. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? I added the folder with the code for the non local median filter to the Matlab path using `path`, and I also copied the files in the folder where I have my script.

Here's the code:

```
IM(m,:,:) = fitsread(Image.fits);
Options.kernelratio=4;
Options.windowratio=4;
Options.verbose=true;
J=NLMF(IM,Options);
figure,
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(IM); title('Noisy image')
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(J); title('NL-means image');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because this function is a .c file that you need to compile in order to use with Matlab, along with those functions as well:

```
vectors_nlmeans_single.c
image2vectors_single.c
vectors_nlmeans_double.c
```

If you look closely in the commented part of the file NLMF.m, you will see this:

```
% First Compile c-code!!!!, with :
%   mex vectors_nlmeans_single.c -v
%   mex image2vectors_single.c -v
%   mex vectors_nlmeans_double.c -v
%   mex image2vectors_double.c -v
```

I can't test it right now but that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you have any clue why Matlab crashes after I compile the .c files?

Comment: you're welcome! Mhh my knowledge about this is quite limited so I guess Google would be a better help than me :)